# Always eager load association with entity

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Is it possible to always eager load an association when an entity is loaded. For example

```
class Book
  has_many :chapters
end

class Chapters
  belongs_to :book
end

book = Book.find_by_title('Moby Dick')
```

I know that you can eager load in the call to find ie. `book = Book.find_by_title( 'Moby Dick', :include => :chapters)` but in this case I know that any time I find a book I always want the chapters eager loaded without needing to remember the `:include =>` parameter.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can include a "default_scope" in your model.

For Rails 4:

```
class Book
  has_many :chapters
  default_scope { includes(:chapters) }
end
```

For Rails 3:

```
class Book
  has_many :chapters
  default_scope includes(:chapters)
end
```

For Rails 2:

```
class Book
  has_many :chapters
  default_scope :include => :chapters
end
```

Comment: and for Rails 4: default_scope { includes(:chapters) }

Comment: `default_scope { includes(:chapters) }` doesn't seem to work with my rails 4.2.x and throws a `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`, however `default_scope ->{ includes(:chapters) }` did work for me

Comment: @CyrilDD That's surprising -- the docs for 4.2.1 say that `default_scope { ... }` is still valid (i.e. you can still pass it a block instead of a proc) http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-default_scope

Comment: Ah I think I know then, it's probably because I'm using Mongoid instead of ActiveRecord. So for Mongoid users, no blocks allowed :(. EDIT : Yeah, the [Mongoid doc](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html) mentions default_scopes can only be criterias or procs